# ReactJS Onclick not working for generated elements

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am generating a list of elements with:

**LeftPanel.js**

```
if (this.state.trader_or_team == 'trader') {
            itemList = users.map(u => <User key={u.id} user={u}
                                            selected={this.props.selected_trader && this.props.selected_trader.id == u.id}
                                            onClick={this.props.handleTraderSelection.bind(this, u)}
            />);
        } else {
            itemList = teams.map(t => <Team key={t.id} team={t}
                                            selected={this.props.selected_team && this.props.selected_team.id == t.id}
                                            onClick={this.props.handleTeamSelection.bind(this, t)}
            />)
        }
```

handleTeamSelection/handleTraderSelection are in the parent component:

**TargetManager.js**

```
handleTraderSelection(selected_trader) {
        console.log('test')
        this.setState({
            selected_trader
        });
    }

    handleTeamSelection(selected_team) {
        this.setState({
            selected_team
        });
    }
```

They are passed down as props:

```
<LeftPanel
                                   handleTraderSelection={::this.handleTraderSelection}
                                   handleTeamSelection={::this.handleTeamSelection}
                        />
```

And rendered:

**LeftPanel.js**

```
return(
    <div className="item-container">
        {itemList}
    </div>
)
```

When I click on any of the elements nothing happen at all. What is going wrong?

---

It appears to break when I bind something to it, in the render method of LeftPanel.js:

```
render() {
    this.props.handleTraderSelection()
    ...
```

Works,

```
render() {
    this.props.handleTraderSelection.bind(this)
    ...
```

Does not work.

Answer (score 2):

Try binding the `handleTraderSelection` and `handleTeamSelection` function like

```
handleTraderSelection = (selected_trader) => {
        console.log('test')
        this.setState({
            selected_trader
        });
    }

    handleTeamSelection = (selected_team) => {
        this.setState({
            selected_team
        });
    }
```

I have been following the conventional method to call the parent function like

```
handleTraderSelection = (value) => {
   this.props.handleTraderSelection(value);
}
handleTeamSelection= (value) => {
   this.props.handleTeamSelection(value);
}
if (this.state.trader_or_team == 'trader') {
            itemList = users.map(u => <User key={u.id} user={u}
                                            selected={this.props.selected_trader && this.props.selected_trader.id == u.id}
                                            onClick={this.handleTraderSelection.bind(this, u)}
            />);
        } else {
            itemList = teams.map(t => <Team key={t.id} team={t}
                                            selected={this.props.selected_team && this.props.selected_team.id == t.id}
                                            onClick={this.handleTeamSelection.bind(this, t)}
            />)
        }
```

and it works for me well.

Comment: I get exactly the same result as before :(

Comment: Also try <LeftPanel
                                   handleTraderSelection={this.handleTraderSelection.bind(this)}
                                   handleTeamSelection={this.handleTeamSelection.bind(this)}
                        />  . I dont think that it makes any difference though

Comment: Nope, same result, :: is just shorthand for .bind(this)

Comment: Your answer was useful so I +1, it's my fault for not putting onClick event on the elements.

Comment: No problem, glad that you figured it out]

Answer (score 0):

I was missing my onClick for my elements...:

```
export default class User extends Component {

    render() {
        return (
            <div onClick={this.props.onClick}>
            ...
```